# RSpec with website format validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, factory-bot, shoulda

I'm using rails4, factory_ girl, rspec and shoulda matchers. If I run rspec with the code below I get this error:

```
Product should validate that :website cannot be empty/falsy, producing a custom validation error on failure
 Failure/Error: self.website = "http://#{self.website}" unless self.website[/^https?/]

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

If I delete `unless self.website[/^https?/]` from the `format_website` method I get this error:

```
Product did not properly validate that :website cannot be empty/falsy,
   producing a custom validation error on failure.
     After setting :website to ‹nil› -- which was read back as ‹"http://"›
     -- the matcher expected the Product to be invalid and to produce a
     validation error matching ‹/can't be blank/› on :website. The record
     was indeed invalid, but it produced these validation errors instead:

     * user: ["can't be blank"]
     * name: ["can't be blank"]
     * company: ["can't be blank"]
```

What should I do to make this work?

product model

```
belongs_to :user

validates :name, presence: { message: "can't be blank" }, length: { maximum: 140, message: "can't be longer than 140 characters" }, uniqueness: { message: "already exists" }
validates :company, presence: { message: "can't be blank" }, length: { maximum: 140, message: "can't be longer than 140 characters" }
validates :website, presence: { message: "can't be blank" }, length: { maximum: 140, message: "can't be longer than 140 characters" }

before_validation :format_website
validate :website_validator


def format_website
  self.website = "http://#{self.website}" unless self.website[/^https?/]
end

def website_validator
  self.errors.add :website, "format is invalid!" unless website_valid?
end

def website_valid?
  !!website.match(/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-=\?]*)*\/?$/)
end
```

factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    name { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
    company { Faker::Company.name }
    website { 'https://example.com' }
    user
  end
end

it { is_expected.to callback(:format_website).before(:validation) } #this one is not important, if I take out it still gives the same error
it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name).with_message(/can't be blank/) }
it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:company).with_message(/can't be blank/) }
it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:website).with_message(/can't be blank/) }
it { is_expected.to belong_to(:user) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ensure that `website` is not `nil`.

```
def format_website
  return if website.blank?

  self.website = "http://#{self.website}" unless self.website[/^https?/]
end
```

In that case, if `self.website == nil`, you'll try to call the method `[]` on a nil object, hence the first error.

For the second case, the answer is in the return you have from rspec:

> After setting :website to ‹nil› -- which was read back as ‹"http://"›

Your method `format_website` returns `"http://"`, which is because website is nil.

Comment: born4new, I didn't ask properly this question. I'd like to know how I can resolve this issue  to make the validator work. Should I use other kind of validation?

Comment: Again, hard to say without seing the specs that are causing the issue, but I'm pretty sure that when you create your model with FactoryGirl, you don't instantiate the `website` attribute. So do that and it should fix it.

Comment: Could you please add the code of the failing spec as well?

Comment: For some reason in you specs, `self.website` is nil when you call it inside the `format_website` method. I'd try to put a `binding.pry` (pry gem) inside the `format_website` when launching your specs to see why there is such a thing happening.

Comment: born4new, can I ask what you are using for website validation? I asked this question to figure out what the best approach is. I just used this rspec example to show that this validator is not the best.

Comment: Your validations look good at this stage, and ActiveRecord validations are a standard way to do that. Your problem here is that you have a `before_validation` that does not take into account the fact that a website can actually be `nil`, and when it is, it simply crashes. I updated the code above to reflect what I would change in your validation.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I checked your answer. Don't you think this would be better: I will use after_validation callback for formatting the website, so if the website is nil then the user has to resubmit the form and after that I can format the website.

Comment: That would work only if you don't validate that your website has to have an http(s):// prefix. But yeah it's good too ☺️